# React simple "Hello World" won't render

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've been googling around, and looking here on StackOverflow and I have seen this question pop up, but they all seem very case specific to what the people who asked, and none of the solutions have worked in my case.

So a little context: I have a very simple message board with a back-end on Spring boot, which works fine. However, I have problems trying to integrate React. I have a home.html page that currently looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org/">

<head>
<title>SilbBoard :-)</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<!-- FONT
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600"
 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- CSS
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

<!-- Favicon
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.6.1/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.6.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
 <h1>Welcome to SilbBoard!</h1>
 <div id="root"></div>
 
  <script src="js/app.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Most of the meta data comes from the Skeleton boilerplate, which works fine.
Then I have a javascript file which, for testing purposes, only contains the following:

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

However, this very simple h1 with "Hello world" won't render in my webpage, nor does it give me any errors.

Is there something I'm missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open your web console, it's trying to tell you something. :-)

Comment: remove the import statements from `app.js` file, and put this script (babel standalone) in head: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.js" />`

Comment: @MayankShukla: Always important to point out that the in-browser transpiler is not for production use. (The above is clearly just learning, but it's still worth pointing out.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder correct, forgot to mention that :)

Comment: I apologize for the month-ish long response, I've spend most of this time trying to really get into it and you guys really helped! I still can't say I entirely dominate react, but I'm understanding the concepts. Thank you!'

Answer (score 1):

The script file you're using doesn't support `import` because it's targeted at web browsers, which are only just now getting support for JavaScript's modules. With the scripts you're using, `React` and `ReactDOM` are defined as globals. No need for `import`.

Separately, browsers don't natively support JSX. To use it, you would need to use a transpiler of some kind. Typically you include the transpiler step in the build process, and then send the resulting transpiled code to the browser. That said, you **can** use in-browser transpiling, but it's best not used for production purposes.

For instance, Stack Overflow's Stack Snippets use [Babel's](http://babeljs.io) in-browser transpiling behind the scenes if you tick the "Use BabelJS / ES2015" checkbox:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.6.1/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.6.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
```

I suggest reading through the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/) a bit more, in particular the [Try React](https://reactjs.org/docs/try-react.html) and [Add React to a New App](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-new-app.html) pages.